# Mongoengine python3 Embedded Document has no attribute _is_document

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am creating my a document having a field as EmbeddedDocument using  mongoengine.

But I am getting the following error :

AttributeError: 'EmbeddedDocument' object has no attribute '_is_document'

Doing some reasearch I found that the code of mongoengine is written in python 2  and do make it work properly install it using pip3. Did the same still not working.

```
class DataImportNodeInfo(EmbeddedDocument):

    provider_id = fields.IntField(required=False)
    carrier_name = fields.StringField(required=False)
    basepath = fields.StringField(required=False)
    log_tobe_imported = fields.ListField(required=False)


class DataImportConnectionInfo(EmbeddedDocument):

    host = fields.StringField(required=True)
    user_login = fields.StringField(required=False)
    user_pwd = fields.StringField(required=False)


class DataImportNode(DynamicDocument):

    # Meta variables
    meta = {
    'collection': str(KonnectDAConstants.DATA_IMPORT_NODES)
    }

    cmd = fields.StringField(required=True)
    import_source = fields.StringField(required=True)
    import_type = fields.StringField(required=True)
    active = fields.BooleanField(required=True)
    info = fields.EmbeddedDocument(DataImportNodeInfo, required=True)
    connection = fields.EmbeddedDocument(DataImportConnectionInfo, required=True)
```

> AttributeError: 'EmbeddedDocument' object has no attribute '_is_document'

Comment: Just in case some one faces this, I was using the wrong attribute of fields.
It should be fields.EmbeddedDocumentField instead of fields.EmbeddedDocument.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `EmbeddedDocumentField` instead of `EmbeddedDocument` in `DataImportNode`:

```
info = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(DataImportNodeInfo, required=True)
connection = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(DataImportConnectionInfo, required=True)
```

Since the `EmbeddedDocumentField` is used to reference the `EmbeddedDocument`.

Comment: Thank you this helped me. You made me realize how dumb mistake i made XD